# How to write VoiceMail dialplans in asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I have some extensions for which i have written dialplans.Now i want to add voicemail feature in it but i dont know how to add it in the existing dialplan.What are the other settings i need to do to achieve this.I am running asterisk on Ubuntu machine.Here is my extention.conf file ..

```
[others]

[my-phones]
exten => 2000,1,Dial(SIP/2000)
exten => 2001,1,Dial(SIP/2001)
exten => 2002,1,Dial(SIP/2002)
```

Please help me as i am very novice in this field.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was working with Asterisk [the WIKI](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Adding+Voice+Mail+to+Dialplan+Extensions) saved me so many times. Here is an example of how to do the extension configuration

```
exten => 6000,1,Answer(500)
exten => 6000,n,Playback(hello-world)
exten => 6000,n,Hangup()

exten => 6001,1,Dial(SIP/demo-alice,20)
exten => 6001,n,VoiceMail(6001@vm-demo,u)

exten => 6002,1,Dial(SIP/demo-bob,20)
exten => 6002,n,VoiceMail(6002@vm-demo,u)

exten => 6500,1,Answer(500)
exten => 6500,n,VoiceMailMain(@vm-demo)
```

And [here if you need to know more about how to configure asterisk for voicemail](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Configuring+Voice+Mail+Boxes)

Comment: http://voip-info.org have more info. Also "Asterisk the Future of Telephony" book can help alot.